# Weird sqLite database string file path error

Tags: c, string, sqlite

So, I'm planning to use sqlite3 to update skype's main.db file.

I use sqlite3_open function to open the connection like this.

```
int rc = sqlite3_open(filepath,db);
```

I'm trying to do the filepath string dynamically, but a weird error is driving me crazy.

I have two strings szFile and szFilePath, szFile being a test string which will contain the actual path of the db file, and szFilePath is the same string only this time dynamically generated by a function.

The thing is just before the execution of sqlite3_open function, both strings as you see on the screenshot are identical, I even posted memory for you to see.

Look at pictures: 
[Picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzNtr.jpg)
[Picture 2](http://i56.tinypic.com/121rgqa.jpg)

Now, despite being completely identical, no matter how many times I run this code ONLY szFile works, with the other one giving me a "cannot open file path" error, and completely confusing me. Also, I don't no if this is normal, but by setting a breakpoint at the next if, I can see that szFilePath loses it's value (is filled with c hex values).

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're returning a char* that points to an array *on the stack* - as soon as you return from the function `szGetFilePath`, this pointer is quite possibly pointing to junk (it will definitely point to junk after a couple of levels of additional calls - when the values on the stack are overwritten).

You can either return a dynamically allocated array of char (i.e. `malloc`ed) from the function (and remember to `free` it later), or pass a pointer to a char array through to `szGetFilePath` and put the character data into this.

Comment: @Panayiotis - answer modified to give you a couple of options.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Managed to get it working with the second option, although I would like to know how to do it with dynamic allocation as well.

Would you be kind enough to give me a code example of how to do it with malloc?

Answer (score 0):

C isn't my strong point but are you perhaps not sending through a UTF-16 string to a function that accepts a UTF-8 string?
http://sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html

Answer (score 0):

`szGetFilePath` is returning the reference of a local variable(`szPathAppData`). On returning from the function call, **unwinding** of the stack begins.

```
 char* szGetFilePath( char* szAccountName )
 {
     char *szPathAppData = calloc(128,1) ; // Allocating memory on heap
     // ....

     return szPathAppData ;
 }

  // You need to free the resources acquired on heap by using free.
  //  free(szPathAppData) ;
```

Comment: @Mahesh How will I free up the resources, if szPathAppDate does not exist outside the function scope? I'm getting some nasty heap exceptions as well.

Comment: @Panayiotis - I am not sure I correctly understood you. You are just returning a pointer to the location on the heap. And you should be able to free via the variable that collects it. BTW, is the data pointed by `szPathAppData` null terminated ? (`\0`)

Comment: @Panayiotis - Could you please post the code with the modifications made ? ( http://pastebin.com/ )

Comment: @Mahesh Here it is: http://pastebin.com/bbkyiSWY The problem I think is with GetEnvironmentVariableA function. Not sure, have a look at it.

Comment: @Panayiotis - Firstly, `szPathAppData` is not null terminated. `malloc` doesn't zero initialize it's memory block. Instead, use `calloc` - `char *szPathAppData = calloc( 128, 1 );`. At what line, you are getting the run-time exception ?

Comment: @Mahesh Exception occurs at sqlite3_free(szError); ; also GetEnvironmentVariableA no longer fills szPathAppData, leading to an incorrect path.

Thanks

Comment: @Panayiotis - `szError` is an uninitialized pointer. So, freeing it results an runtime error. From the docs - `If an error occurs while evaluating the SQL statements passed into sqlite3_exec(), then execution of the current statement stops and subsequent statements are skipped. If the 5th parameter to sqlite3_exec() is not NULL then any error message is written into memory obtained from sqlite3_malloc() and passed back through the 5th parameter...` http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/exec.html

Comment: @Mahesh So firstly thanks a lot for fixing the pointer runtime.

As for the previous errors, I have found that the cause of them wasn't malloc and null-termination, since the problem still existed until a few minutes ago. Firstly when you asked if it was a null-terminated string and I said yes, it was because GetEnvironmentVariableA writes to a buffer and null-terminates it on it's own, that is why I was seeing it null terminated.

Comment: The mistake with malloc was that instead of allocating malloc(128) you suggested allocating to the size of (128), which was causing GetEnvironmentVariableA to write a 128 chars over a string that was only four bytes long. That was screwing up the path. Secondly, another mistake I've been doing is that GetEnv.Var. had incorrectly its 3rd parameter set to 4 bytes instead of 128 characters (calculating size of pointer instead of whole array, on my original code it worked because I used no pointer). With these I have managed to get it working both with malloc and calloc